# jQuery animation callback not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Hey, if anyone could please help me then it would be much appreciated. Basically, I want to navigate to a new page once this animation has complete. Using the code below, the animation works fine but hen the navigation doesn't happen.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions? Many thanks, Tim

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var driver = $(this).attr('href');

   $(".content-center").animate({height: "0px"}, 500, function(){
        navigate(driver);
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you get any script errors?

Comment: The code you posted is fine. The problems are likely elsewhere, for example in the `navigate()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `navigate` function is not supported on all browsers. Instead, use:

```
window.location.href = driver;
```